# Adding images into homepage using html, css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add two images in a single row on my home page made using html css and bootstrap what should be the size of those images(in pixels). Please tell me how can I make those images responsive? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use class "img-responsive" from bootstrap

Comment: or make the img size in %.

Comment: "what should be the size of those images(in pixels)." — That's a matter of opinion.

Comment: "And how can i make those images responsive?" — That depends on how you want them to respond to changes in window size.

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 dividers in your HTML like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 myfirstimageclass"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mysecondimageclass"></div>
</div>
```

The class `col-md-6` is a Bootstrap class, the other class `myfirstimageclass` is a self made class, place the images as background in your CSS and you are finished:

```
.myfirstimageclass{
     background-image:url(yourfirstimageurl);
     background-size:cover;
     height:300px;
}
.mysecondimageclass{
     background-image:url(yoursecondimageurl);
     background-size:cover;
     height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should choose a reasonable size so they aren't huge is filesize.

Then use bootstrap's `img-responsive` class to make them response.

Here's a link to the [bootstrap documentation for img-responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive).